How return all rows of a group item in Django?
My database is real estate related and has a history of property transactions. I have this code:
    def filter_model(estate, years=[], exact_match=False, distance_km=None):
            query_filter = Q(location__postal_code__isnull=False, sold_histories__isnull=False)

            if distance_km:
                query_filter &= Q(location__point__distance_lte=(
                    estate.location.point, distance_km))
                query_filter &= Q(type=estate.type)
                query_filter &= Q(square_feet__isnull=False)  # >1500
                query_filter &= Q(year_built__isnull=False)
                if estate.type == 2:
                    address = str(estate.location.address).split('#')[0].strip()
                    query_filter &= Q(location__address__icontains=address)

                estates = Estate.objects.prefetch_related(
                    # ? This is for speed up loop.
                    'location__city',
                    'location__neighbourhood',
                    Prefetch('sold_histories', queryset=SoldHistory.objects.order_by('-date'))
                ).filter(query_filter).distinct()
            else:
                if len(years) == 2:
                    query_filter &= Q(sold_histories__date__year=years[0])

                if exact_match:
                    query_filter &= Q(location__city__province__id=estate.location.city.province.id)
                else:
                    query_filter &= Q(location__city__id=estate.location.city.id)

                estates = Estate.objects.prefetch_related(
                    # ? This is for speed up loop.
                    'location__city',
                    'location__neighbourhood',
                    Prefetch('sold_histories', queryset=SoldHistory.objects.filter(date__year__in=years))
                ).filter(query_filter).filter(sold_histories__date__year=years[1]).distinct()

            return [
                [
                    e.id,
                    e.bedrooms,
                    e.type,
                    e.year_built,
                    e.square_feet,
                    e.lot_size,
                    e.location.id,
                    e.location.address,
                    e.location.postal_code,
                    e.location.latitude,
                    e.location.longitude,
                    e.location.city.name if e.location.city else None,
                    e.location.neighbourhood.name if e.location.neighbourhood else None,
                    sh.date,
                    sh.price
                ]
                for e in estates
                for sh in e.sold_histories.all()
            ]

I need to optimize this code. The reason I made the list is that I need to return all history of an address from the database. I am using this code to get data,
km = 1 * 1000 estates_by_km.extend(filter_model(estate=estate, distance_km=km//2))
If I don't return the list it would only return the last history per each address. Is there anyway to return all history of filtered address without making a list?
This code works, I only need to optimize it.

Is making the list a significant overhead compared to the database query?
If you want to process itews from the queryset one by one you might turn this function into a Python generator function. The last part would look like
for e in estates:
    for sh in e.sold_histories.all()
       yield [
          e.id,
          ...
          sh.price
       ]

and the calling code would be
for item in filter_model( estate, other_args...):
    # do something with item, which is a simple list as yield'ed.
    e_id = item[0]
    ...

I would either yield a dict rather than a list, or I would define symbolic names for the indexes into the list ( E_ID=0, E_BEDROOMS = 1, ... etc ) both of which remove a lot of scope for errors. ( For the OP I expect this is teaching grandma to suck eggs, but others may read this).

Thank you for teaching us a new idiom. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_grandmother_to_suck_eggs
